# OPENVAS is not working in FREEBSD

Tags: freebsd, openvas, opnsense

I have installed openvas9 in Opensense(FreeBSD based firewall and routing platform).But when I enter "omp"  in CLI then following error shows.

```
root@user:~ # omp
Shared object "libkrb5.so.11" not found, required by "libssh.so.4"
```

I am new in OPENVAS.

Comment: which version is opensense base on? From where did you install libssh? Try to reinstall libssh